# displaying specific records of a user without using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, html

i have a problem with my coding. when i put 'where' in my query, it does not show anything. but when i do not put 'where' it display all the records. all i want is that, it will display the records of the current user that logged in..

please help me with this.

what will be the code for these?

anyone? :(

it will be a big help. thanks..

This is my query..

```
$query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

whenever i put WHERE , it doesn't display anything.

Comment: The code you have so far is...?

Comment: have some mysql tables? some query example, what you've tried? would help us much ;-)

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);


this is my query.. whenever i put WHERE , it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Could you show us the description of the table members ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by echoing out your $query just before the mysql_query statement, so you can check that it's what you expect.
Then put some error handling in your code to identify if there's a database error being returned:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";
echo $query.'<br />';
$result=mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) {
    die('Error executing query: ' . mysql_errno().' '.mysql_error());
}
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

These are absolute basics that you should always be doing before asking for help.

Also, try escaping $username before using it in your query

Answer (score 0):

You'd better learn how to use `WHERE` correctly. You will need it in the future.

Could you please show us the query that gives all records, the first few lines from that, and the query with `WHERE` that fails?

It should be something like `SELECT * from users WHERE loginname="Smith"`

Of course, you would need to use `WHERE` on a column from the table. So, when you create the table, you should have added a `loginname` column, and whenever you `INSERT` a row, you should set the `loginname` value. If you don't store the loginname, you can't filter on it later. It's not magically remembered.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'"; $result=mysql_query($query); $num=mysql_numrows($result);

Comment: what i'm tryin to say is, when the user is currently logged in, it will automatically display its records. then how will it automatically display? if i manually put that ' WHERE lastname= "Smith" '.. and what if Smith is not the currently user?

Comment: i know its not magically remembered. that's why im saking u guys.. what is the correct code for that.. thanks. :)